# Ros with snappy

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, ros

I'm following this example: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/ros-snap/

The program works fine with roslaunch, and I'm able to create and install the snap. However, when running the snap I get this message. After the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> under the program just restarts and ends up in the same error. Restart - Error - Restart - Error and so on.

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    listener (listener/listener_node)
    talker (talker/talker_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [10106]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to e9e6e48a-4452-11e6-aa90-26946bd3aee5
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [10119]
started core service [/rosout]
process[talker-2]: started with pid [10122]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
process[listener-3]: started with pid [10124]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known snapcraft bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1577557) which is due to a [known snapd bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1576411) where locales are not available to snaps. That snapd bug has existed long enough it's probably time to work around it in that snapcraft example by setting the locale to C.UTF-8. I'll get on that.

UPDATE: Here's the temporary fix: https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/pull/497

UPDATE: This fix is available in snapcraft now.